Get stock list from Chartink screener in Google sheet
I am trying to get stocks list from Chartink.com screener in Google sheet.
But I am not able to do so, Kindly help.
A1 is https://chartink.com/screener/macd-cross-51432
B1 is (+{cash}+(+latest+macd+line(+26+,+12+,+9+)+>+latest+macd+signal(+26+,+12+,+9+)+and+1+day+ago++macd+line(+26+,+12+,+9+)+<=+1+day+ago++macd+signal(+26+,+12+,+9+)+and+latest+close+<=+300+and+latest+rsi(+14+)+>+70+)+)+
C1 is groupcount(+1+where+daily+macd+line(+26+,+12+,+9+)+>+daily+macd+signal(+26+,+12+,+9+)+and+1+day+ago++macd+line(+26+,+12+,+9+)+<=+1+day+ago++macd+signal(+26+,+12+,+9+)),groupcount(+1+where+daily+close+<=+300),groupcount(+1+where+daily+rsi(+14+)+>+70)
function Chartinkupload() {
  // Get the URL, scan_clause, and debug_clause from specific cells
  const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  const scanClause = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1").getValue();
  const debugClause = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C1").getValue();

  // Prepare the payload data
  const payloadData = {
    "scan_clause": scanClause,
    "debug_clause": debugClause
  };

  // Convert payload to JSON string
  const payload = JSON.stringify(payloadData);

  try {
    // Send POST request with JSON payload and muteHttpExceptions option
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      payload: payload,
      contentType: "application/json",
      muteHttpExceptions: true // Added option to mute HTTP exceptions
    });

    // Check for successful response
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      const json = response.getContentText();
      const chartinkData = JSON.parse(json);

      // Write data to the "chartink" sheet starting from cell A1
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("chartink");
      sheet.clear(); // Clear existing data
      sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(json); // Write JSON response to cell A1

      Logger.log("Data written to sheet 'chartink'");
    } else {
      Logger.log("Error fetching data: " + response.getResponseCode());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error during upload: " + error.message);
  }
}

Google sheet should get data like this
Sr. Stock Name  Symbol  Links   % Chg   Price   Volume


Can you please post the contents of the request? As in - the actual value of scanClause and debugClause?

Error I got is:   got error message Exception: Request failed for https://chartink.com returned code 419. Truncated server response: 



What happens if you replace your URL to be https://chartink.com/screener/process? The reason I'm asking this - when I visit the link you provide, and monitor the Network tab of DevTools, I can see that this is the endpoint to which scanClause and debugClause are sent to.
